# Youtube video won't play with Firefox but will with Safari!

Tags: video, firefox, youtube

What can I do to solve this problem ?

On the same iMac, there are several accounts. For one of them, Youtube videos won't play in Firefox, but will with Safari. For the other accounts, Firefox and Safari can play Youtube videos!?

Any hint where I can search to solve the issue ?

EDIT : I'm sorry. I can not flag anything because this long lasting (several months) problem has been solved, and I don't know how! I didn't change anything. This must be a side effect of something I did. Probably on my Admin Account. The mystery stays forever...

Comment: Are you sure that Safari is playing the youtube videos using flash? It's possible that the user is using HTML5 to play videos in YouTube. There exist extensions like [this one](http://www.verticalforest.com/youtube5-extension/) for such thing. **What do the media player controls in the YouTube look like?**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you don't have Adobe Flash plugin installed you need to [do so](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and give it another go.
Do you have by any chance the Firefox "Flashblock" extension installed?!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

- Flash plugin is properly installed and activated in FireFox for all accounts (ie: other flash stuff works)
- The accounts aren't using some sort of blocker plugin (ads, flash etc)